# How to iterate and update a dictionary that contains a URL in Python?

Tags: python

**Issue**

I am trying to retrieve reviews from a particular website using selenium and python. I initially was able to iterate through the web pages of the website as they were paginated with page numbers but since they changed how they paginate their web pages, I have been having problems in iterating through the pages and scraping the data I require.

The code block I use to open the website, retrieve the href link and append it to the URL is:

```
loc_dict = {'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.veinclinics.com'}

proxies = ['172.241.244.85:29842',
'23.106.16.58:29842',
'23.80.148.127:29842',
]

used_user_agents = []

stdev_time = 2
mean_time = 15

with open('user_agents.txt') as f:
    user_agents = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        user_agents.append(line)
print "Using "+str(len(user_agents))+" user agents"

soup_list = []
fail_list =[]

for item in loc_dict:
    flag = "bad"
    while flag == "bad":
        print item
                
        wait_time = abs(random.gauss(mean_time,stdev_time))

#selecting random user agent
        used_agent = user_agents[int(random.uniform(1,len(user_agents)))]
    
        print "Using agent: " + used_agent
    
        while used_agent in used_user_agents:
            used_agent = user_agents[int(random.uniform(1,len(user_agents)))]
        
        used_user_agents.append(used_agent)
        if len(used_user_agents) > 4:
            used_user_agents = []
               
#random proxy
        PROXY = proxies[int(random.uniform(1,len(proxies)))]
        print PROXY
    
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
        #options.add_argument("user-agent=%s" % used_agent)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\svaddi\Trustpilot-ADCS\chromedriver.exe')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        
        driver.get(item)
        html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")  
    time.sleep(wait_time)      
        driver.close()
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
        
        browser_check = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'row'})
        print browser_check
        
        if browser_check==None:
            print "browser worked"
            flag= "good"
       
        
        else:
            if "no longer supports this browser" in str(browser_check):
                time.sleep(120.0)
                continue
            else:
                print "browser worked but has that row"
                flag= "good"
                
        find_all_a = soup.find_all("a", {"rel":"next"}, href=True)
        for el in find_all_a:
            tags = el['href']
            print tags
            
        clickable_link = ['https://www.trustpilot.com' + str(tags)]
        real_url = ''.join(clickable_link)
        print real_url
```

real_url gets me the url for the next page that I'd need to scrape. How do I update loc_dict with real_url?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your code correctly using to make it easier for people to answer your questions.

Comment: do you get error? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you would use Selenium methods instead of BeautifulSoup then you could simply `.click()` it.  Now you have to use `driver.get(real_url)`. But still you would have to run it in some loop which will run the same code for new page.

Comment: `loc_dict` is a `set` with a single item

Comment: @GAP2002 Thank you, sorry about the formatting - I'm new to posting on stackoverflow and am still finding my way navigating the site. Will make sure to format it properly next time I post a question.

Comment: @furas No I do not get an error. I get the URL for the next page from the href. And I agree, I did try to use .click() and iterate it but as balderman points out, since it is a set, .click() does not seem to work. I did try to convert the real_url into a normal string but obviously python cannot click on string. I am confused as to how to iterate on the original URL.

Comment: if you have string then use `driver.get(new_url)` to load next page. If it is relative path then add domain `driver.get( original_url + new_url)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here... starting with the fact that `loc_dict` is actually a `set`, not a `dict`. Given how you're using it as more of a list-y/set-y structure, that fact doesn't seem to be an issue.

However, if you attempt to modify the set while you're iterating over it (using the `for` iterator, you'll get an error like this: `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`

So what you might want to do is have *two* sets: one of urls to process, and one of urls that you're done with. Then iterate with a `while` loop and a condition, so that you're not technically iterating over the set, just its condition. Like so:

```py
loc_set = {'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.veinclinics.com'}
processed_set = set()
proxies = ['172.241.244.85:29842',
'23.106.16.58:29842',
'23.80.148.127:29842',
]

used_user_agents = []

stdev_time = 2
mean_time = 15

with open('user_agents.txt') as f:
    user_agents = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        user_agents.append(line)
print "Using "+str(len(user_agents))+" user agents"

soup_list = []
fail_list =[]

while len(loc_set) > 0:
    item = loc_set.pop()
    processed_set.add(item)
    flag = "bad"
    while flag == "bad":
        print item
                
        wait_time = abs(random.gauss(mean_time,stdev_time))

#selecting random user agent
        used_agent = user_agents[int(random.uniform(1,len(user_agents)))]
    
        print "Using agent: " + used_agent
    
        while used_agent in used_user_agents:
            used_agent = user_agents[int(random.uniform(1,len(user_agents)))]
        
        used_user_agents.append(used_agent)
        if len(used_user_agents) > 4:
            used_user_agents = []
               
#random proxy
        PROXY = proxies[int(random.uniform(1,len(proxies)))]
        print PROXY
    
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
        #options.add_argument("user-agent=%s" % used_agent)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\svaddi\Trustpilot-ADCS\chromedriver.exe')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        
        driver.get(item)
        html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")  
    time.sleep(wait_time)      
        driver.close()
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
        
        browser_check = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'row'})
        print browser_check
        
        if browser_check==None:
            print "browser worked"
            soup_list.append([placeid,soup])
            flag= "good"
       
        
        else:
            if "no longer supports this browser" in str(browser_check):
                time.sleep(120.0)
                continue
            else:
                print "browser worked but has that row"
                soup_list.append([placeid,soup])
                flag= "good"
                
        find_all_a = soup.find_all("a", {"rel":"next"}, href=True)
        for el in find_all_a:
            tags = el['href']
            print tags
            
        clickable_link = ['https://www.trustpilot.com' + str(tags)]
        real_url = ''.join(clickable_link)
        print real_url
        if real_url not in processed_set and real_url not in loc_set:
            loc_set.add(real_url)
```

Now, because we've added each `item` to `processed_set`, it will contain each of the URLs that you wanted to process. And since you `pop()` all of the items out of `loc_set` (what I've re-named `loc_dict`), it will terminate the loop when all of the URLs have been processed. I also added a catch in there at the end:

```py
if real_url not in processed_set and real_url not in loc_set: ...
```

This is to make sure that you don't process any given link more than once.

Also, this code appears to be written in Python 2, which has been dead for over a year now. Move to Python 3. If you're on a mac, it's `python3` since they refuse to alias `python`.